# php instagram how to search photo , like on sepcifics tag name

Tags: rest, curl, instagram, instagram-api

https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/pink/media/recent?access_token=*****1.*****427.05*************************42421&scope=likes+comments+relationships+basic

I use Tag **pink**  in this api for search photo and like  it show my upload details.
But I want search other user photo and like which have pink **tag** 
I'm geting this Error.>>

```
{"pagination": {"deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"}, 
 "meta": {"code": 200}, 
 "data": []}
```

please

```
next_max_id
min_tag_id
max_tag_id
min_id
```

this all I used But this is not solution..
please

Comment: Deprecation warnings are normally not fatal, they are just preparing you for a change that will happen in the next release. So this may be nothing to do with the error, or as you get a code:200 and no data, maybe there is just nothing returned by the search

Comment: Yes Sir . Your right.

Comment: I have to find specific tag related other user photos and likes.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are in Sandbox mode? You will only see your posts (and your sandbox approved users) in API response, and total posts returned is restricted to 20 in sandbox mode. Here is more info on sandbox mode:https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/

Use instagram app to add a photo with `#pink` and then check API, you will see just that post. Once you get your app reviewed by instagram and approved, you will get all data in response, not just yours.

You API call should look just like this:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/pink/media/recent?access_token=XXX
```

You should not have `scope=likes+comments+relationships+basic`, scope should be specified during authentication to get access_token, and for `tags` API, you need `public_content` scope.

Comment: Thank you .but I'm developing website every IG user should go from my website login and enter  IG username and password. and redirect my website ...

Comment: how can I get authentication Permission.